# How to swap the byte order for individual words in a vector in ARM/ACLE

Tags: arm, simd, endianness, cpu-word, neon

I usually write portable C code and try to adhere to strictly standard-conforming subset of the features supported by compilers.

However, I'm writing codes that exploits the ARM v8 Cryptography extensions to implement SHA-1 (and SHA-256 some days later). A problem that I face, is that, FIPS-180 specify the hash algorithms using big-endian byte order, whereas most ARM-based OS ABIs are little-endian.

If it's a single integer operand (on general purpose register) I can use the [APIs specified for the next POSIX standard](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=162), but I'm working with SIMD registers, since it's where ARMv8 Crypto works.

So **Q**: how do I swap the byte order for words in a vector register on ARM? I'm fine with assembly answers, but prefer ACLE intrinsics ones.

Comment: ARM has an arbitrary byte shuffle, `tbl`.  Not sure if there's anything more efficient or specific (e.g. to avoid needing a vector constant for the shuffle control).  `tbl` is fairly efficient, but IIRC not quite as good throughput as some other SIMD instructions on some CPUs.  ARM has intrinsics for their SIMD instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's very interesting. I could use it someday when needed. For now, I've found what's sufficient for my purpose.

Comment: @PeterCordes `tbl` and `tbx` are low throughput, high latency neon instructions, especially unbelievably sluggish on Cortex-A57 and Cortex-A72.

Comment: Endianess is the lesser evil on ARM for your problem. NEON supports polynomial multiplications (carry-less multiply) in addition to `aesa` instructions. Once fully implemented, you won't recognize your code again. It's that powerful. https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0501/f/preface

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE x86 also supports multiplication over binary polynomial. These instructions are necessary for implementing GCM AEAD encryption and XTS disk encryption. Most side-channel resistant alternatives don't have nearly that much efficiency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The instructions are:

- `REV16` for byte-swapping short integers,
- `REV32` for byte-swapping 32-bit integers, and
- `REV64` for byte-swapping 64-bit integers.

They can be used to swap the byte **AND** word order of any length that's strictly less than what their name indicates. They're defined in section C7.2.219~C7.2.221 of *Arm® Architecture Reference Manual
Armv8, for A-profile architecture* "DDI0487G_b_armv8_arm.pdf"

e.g. `REV32` can be used to reverse the order of 2 short integers within each 32-bit words:

```
[00][01][02][03][04][05][06][07]
to
[02][03][00][01][06][07][04][05]
```

Their intrinsics are defined in a separate document: *Arm Neon Intrinsics Reference* "advsimd-2021Q2.pdf"

To swap the 32-bit words in a 128-bit vector, use the `vrev32q_u8` instrinsic. Relevant `vreinterpretq_*` intrinsics need to be used to re-interpret the type of the operands.